# Confused about (new?) feature in TABS for Nintendo Switch

Tags: nintendo-switch, totally-accurate-battle-simulator

So I just got TABS for Switch, and noticed in multiplayer that certain units added to the number of units by more than one. For example clubber would count as 1 unit but reaper would count as 5. I played TABS on my friend's Xbox, and this wasn't the case. Is there a way to disable this feature? So far my only workaround has been to disable unit count entirely, but I would like a better solution.

Comment: The Switch version seems to have some limitations in place due to performance on the Switch. I wonder if this is part of that.